# X $\wedge$ (Y $\wedge$ Z) homeomorphic to (X $\wedge$ Y) $\wedge Z$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

> X $\wedge$ (Y $\wedge$ Z) homeomorphic to (X $\wedge$ Y) $\wedge$ Z

I tried expanding the wedges as in $X \wedge Y$ $=$ $X \times Y / (X \vee Y)$ but that does not seem to work

Any help or hints would be appreciated

Regards

Comment: This isn't true without extra assumptions on the spaces.  (compactly generated?)

Comment: @Randall I just copied the question given and wrote what I tried (I also think we need extra assumptions even hausdorffness would help with compactness)

Comment: The fundamental reason this isn't true is that it is not always true that the levelwise quotient of a product $X \times Y /(x,y) \sim (x',y)$ is the same as $X/(x \sim x') \times Y$. If this is homework, I suggest including this as a hypothesis for all your spaces and pointing out that it isn't true in general.

Comment: For a counterexample see https://mathoverflow.net/q/196084. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smash_product.